# R - Error in writeOGR - A NULL unknown data type

Tags: r

Attempting to export SPDF in R and receive NA Null

```
> writeOGR(polygon, ("polygon.shp"), layer="polygon", driver="ESRI Shapefile")

Error in writeOGR(polygon, ("polygon.shp"),  : NA NULL unknown data type
```

The SPDF contains the following:

```
> polygon
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1275 
extent      : 139.5756, 139.9322, 35.54359, 35.80955  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- nrow(polygon)
d <- data.frame(row.names = 1:x, id = 1:x)
spd <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polygon,data = d)
writeOGR(spd, ("polygon.shp"), layer="polygon", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```